# Funcion doble sumatoria Haskell

Tags: haskell, funcion

Necesito implementar la siguiente función en Haskell (Sumatoria doble):

[image: Sumatoria doble]

Llegué a esto:

```
g2 :: Int -> Float
g2 n | n == 0 = 0
     | otherwise = (g2 (n-1))^fromIntegral(g2 (n-1)) + fromIntegral((sumatoria n)^n)`
```

Armé la estructura de la sumatoria y llegué a que podía usar recursión con `g2 (n-1) ^ g2(n-1)`, aunque no se si es válido.

Answer (score 0):

Expresar `g2(n)` en función de `g2(n-1)` es algo más complicado de lo que indicas. De todos modos, es más sencillo que eso. No es necesario usar recursividad, tan sólo compresión de listas:

```
g2 :: Integer -> Integer
g2 n = sum [ i^j | i <- [1..n], j <- [1..n] ]
```

He usado `Integer` ya que son cantidades que muy pronto se hacen enormes para los tipos `Int` o `Float`.